# Sort Arraylist contains file path

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I need to sort this array with filename, each item is from different path.

how do i sort this array based on **file names**.

```
ArrayList<String> sort = new ArrayList<>();

        sort.add("/etc/fest/gerts.png");
        sort.add("/etc/fest/ase.png");
        sort.add("/etc/test/zer.png");
        sort.add("/etc/fest/dse.png");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in Java 8:

Here in this it will first get the file names by substringing the string based on last index of "/". And then sort based on the same.

```
list.sort(Comparator
    .comparing(s -> s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
```

In case you are not on Java 8.
You can create a custom Comparator like this and then call the `Collections` API.

```
public class SubstringComparator implements Comparator {
  public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    String s1 = o1.tostring().substring(o1.tostring().lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    String s2 = o2.tostring().substring(o2.tostring().lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
    // or, more concisely:
    // return o1.toString().substring(1).equals(o2.toString().substring(1));
  }
}
```

And then call it as below:

```
SubstringComparator comparator = new SubstringComparator();
Collections.sort(list, comparator );
```

Comment: Plz accept the answer and also vote if it was useful

Answer (score 1):

This will sort only by the file names, ignoring the parent folders:

**Using JAVA 8**

```
sort.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> new File(o).getName().toUpperCase()));
sort.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Using JAVA < 8**

```
sort.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return new File(o1).getName().toUpperCase().compareTo(new File(o2).getName().toUpperCase());
    }
});
for (String s : sort) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
/etc/fest/ase.png
/etc/fest/dse.png
/etc/fest/gerts.png
/etc/test/zer.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Collections.sort(sort);
```

Comment: This won't sort by file name sonly, it will consider also the parent folders, which op didn't ask for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Collection method sort

```
Collections.sort(sort);
```

Comment: This won't sort by file name sonly, it will consider also the parent folders, which op didn't ask for.